# Can use excel within windows docker container?

Tags: excel, docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I want to use excel within a docker container (.net core 2.0) but dont know how to adjust my dockerfile accordingly (or if its even possible).  I am subscribed to office 365.

Below is my dockerfile; thanks

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "mpx.dll"]
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working?